# Controlling the order in which layers are rendered in Mapzen's Tangram?

Tags: javascript, mapzen, tangram

Tangram uses a YAML mapping to define layers, which means that order is undefined. So, how do you control the order in which layers are rendered?

Answer (score 2):

You add an explicit `order` parameter under the draw style. https://tangrams.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Syntax-Reference/draw/#order